# How to convert a String object into TextField Object in javafx?

Tags: java, javafx

I have a method that clears a text field on a mouse click event. But this method need to be implemented for every Text-Field I wanted to apply it.

Alternatively I have tried to create a common method that  returns the element id and use that element id to clear the associated element. But this element id returns as a String. I cannot convert it to a Text-Field. Is there any other way to implement above logic? Thanks in advance.

```
public void clearUserName(MouseEvent event) {
        String textFiledName =((Control) event.getSource()).getId(); //returns as a String
    } // Cannot convert textFiledName to a TextField
```

Comment: you want to set String or Convert String object into TextField Object

Comment: How would you be able to convert a `String` to a UI element? Have you skipped all the basics of Java?

Comment: @Kayaman well he having problem to put it in a word what exactly he want http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: Yap my wording may be ambiguous. B'bek Shakya have got it correctly !! I just want to Convert String object into TextField Object

Answer (score 3):

You could attach the `TextField`s as `userData` to those `Control`s, e.g.

```
Control control = ...
control.setUserData(textField);
```

```
public void clearUserName(MouseEvent event) {
    TextField textField = (TextField) ((Node) event.getSource()).getUserData();
    ...
}
```

If the `userData` property is already in use, you could also use the [`properties` map of `Node`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#getProperties--) to store a reference to the `TextField` instead.

Using a helper method to create the `TextField`s could reduce the code duplication by setting the result as `userData` to a `Control` passed as parameter.

```
private static TextField createTextField(Control control) {
    TextField result = new TextField();
    control.setUserData(result);
    return result;
}
```

---

An alternative would be using reflection to access a field by name, but I wouldn't recommend it. This won't work for local variables, but there simply is no way to access local variables by name.

---

Another possibility would be to add a method for creating the `TextField`s that also gets the id as parameter and adds the `TextField`s to a `Map<String, TextField>`.

```
private final Map<String, TextField> textFields = new HashMap<>();

private TextField createTextField(String controlId) {
    TextField result = new TextField();
    textFields.put(controlId, result);
    return result;
}

public void clearUserName(MouseEvent event) {
    String textFiledName = ((Control) event.getSource()).getId();
    TextField textField = textFields.get(textFiledName);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yap but still I would have to define all my TextFields as UserData right ?
Can we use a common method without specifying all the textfields we have ?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use following method...

```
public void clearUserName(MouseEvent event) {
    userName.clear(); //Here userName is the label name.
}
```